# How to select a multiple classes inside a two condition class?

Tags: css, css-selectors

HTML code:

```
<html class="mobile portrait">
    <body>
        <div>
            <header>
                <img class="company_logo">
            </header>
            <section>
                <div>
                    <img class="company_logo">
                </div>
            </section>
            <footer>
                <img class="company_logo">
            </footer>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

In order to `display: none;`, How can I apply one rule to `.company_logo` while `.mobile .portrait`?:

---

***Update***: *Edited HTML code to add multiple `company_logo`. Code deleted from the question:*

```
/* CSS code */
.mobile .portrait > body > div > header > .company_logo {
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: `.mobile.portrait  .company_logo` ? This says find me an element with the class of `company_logo` that is inside an element with both classes `mobile, portrait`

Comment: BTW, it should be `.mobile.portrait > ....` (without the space)

Comment: What @JuanMendes said without the space between `.mobile` and `.portrait` since they're on the same tag. `.mobile.portrait .company_logo`

Comment: @BrianRay Yeah, thanks,  I missed that

Comment: It depends on whether you specifically only want to target the `.company_logo` that corresponds to that hierarchy and not any others.

Comment: @BoltClock Hide all `.company_logo`s. I'll update the question, thanks.

Comment: @quantme If you want to hide all of them why don't you just use `.company_logo`?

Comment: @PatrickGregorio Because must works only while `<html class="mobile portrait">`. An outsourcing company provides HTML and JS code, I do the CSS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```css
    /* Matches elements with the class of company_logo 
       that are inside an element 
       with both "mobile" and "portrait" classes */
    
    .mobile.portrait .company_logo {
       /* style here */
    }
```